# What is the default TransformerFactory?

Tags: java, xslt, jaxp

I'm using JAXP XSLT APIs (javax.xml.transform) to transform xml file.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
transformer.transform(inputSource, outputResult);
```

The javadoc for TransformerFactory says:
It uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine the TransformerFactory implementation class to load:

1. Use the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory system property.
2. Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory. This
       configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format and
       contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class with
       the key being the system property defined above. The jaxp.properties
       file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and it's values
       are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist when the
       first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts are made
       to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the value
       of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been read for the
       first time.
3. Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR
       specification), if available, to determine the classname. The
       Services API will look for a classname in the file
       META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in jars
       available to the runtime.
4. Platform default TransformerFactory instance.

I wonder how to decide which is the default TransformerFactory instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Platform" here is Java-speak for the Java compiler / runtime you are using. So the "platform default" means whatever the JDK decides. In the case of the Oracle JDK, it's a version of the Xalan XSLT 1.0 engine that's built in to the JDK. A different JDK could use a different default.

Comment: Thank you.  How to check which XSLT version (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) is supported by the default xslt processor included with Oracle JDK, for example, Oracle JDK 1.6?

Comment: The default XSLT processor in all current versions of the Oracle JDK supports only XSLT 1.0. But if you want to check for this, you can write a test such as `test="system-property('xsl:version') = 1.0"`

Answer (score 4):

From Oracle JDK 1.7

Class `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`:

Default Transformer is XSLTC (originally forked from Xalan). XSLTC is the compiling version (the 'C' in XSLTC)
`com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`

```
public static TransformerFactory newInstance()
    throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError {
    try {
        return (TransformerFactory) FactoryFinder.find(
        /* The default property name according to the JAXP spec */
        "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
        /* The fallback implementation class name, XSLTC */
        "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    } catch (FactoryFinder.ConfigurationError e) {
        throw new TransformerFactoryConfigurationError(
            e.getException(),
            e.getMessage());
    }
}
```